# I’m getting Static shocks when touching water in Lay-Z-Spa whilst standing on my Astro Turf

Tags: electrical, water, bathtub, pool, grass

In the spa for a while. I bent over to use the net that was sitting on the Astro Turf. I touched the metal handle and got a shock. I got out and stood on the Astro Turf and when I put my finger in the water I got a shock again. It’s like a strong static shock. Any ideas?

Comment: Would check for all electrical faults.  Do imagine there is an electrical connection/power to the spa.  Turn off the breaker for it still fixed.  It can be deadly.

Comment: Gotta agree with @crip659, mostly.   If it's truly a static shock, it would be just for an instant, if it's continuous you have a ground fault or other electrical problem.

Comment: Electrical shocks repeat if you can remove yourself.  Static shocks 99.9% of the time do not repeat between the same two objects, equalizing of potential electrical difference.  Replace still with till in my earlier comment, but do turn off breaker now.

Comment: Turn off power to the spa. Shock gone? Not static.

Comment: Did you have a blower pumping in air, this has been one place I have found on spas that generate static the Astro turf being an insulator can allow metal devices to charge fairly quickly

Comment: Don't tempt fate anymore, either of those incidents would have killed you if conditions had been a bit different.  In fact, if you are in water, a stun is as good as a kill - you drown, and so does the first person who comes along to try to rescue you. Happens *all the time*.

Comment: Re-reading the OP and others comments, my comment was too mild. I didn't notice the repeat occurrence...that's def. not a static shock.   Thanks to others who recognized the danger here, it's bad. Def. a Ground fault...no other explanation.

Answer (score 2):

### Get that spa on GFCI protection. NOW.

This incident could have killed you if the situation had been a little bit different - higher humidity in soil, recent rain, whatever.  Electric shock drownings are an ongoing tragedy, and often kill the first rescuer as well.  In one Texas case, a girl went into a fountain, a friend went in to rescue, and 2 other friends also went in to rescue them - we lost all 4.  It was a mall, and the firemen couldn't find a disconnect. Code now requires GFCI and nearby obvious disconnect switches.

240V "spa panels" are in the $100 range and include a GFCI master breaker, as well as often some spare breaker spaces for smaller circuits.  They serve as both the GFCI protection and the nearby disconnect.   Or, the 240V breaker in the panel can be replaced with a GFCI breaker ($80).

While the GFCI trip will be an annoyance, it will save lives and "force you to" fix the electrical fault.  It is impossible to safely run a spa or hot tub with an electrical fault present.

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR CHECK FOR GROUND FAULT PROTECTION NOW!

There are basically two possibilities here. One is a an actual static shock, which is generally of no real significance. Similar to walking across a carpet in dry weather and touching a door knob and getting a little shock. If that's all it is, there may be some things you can do to mitigate it, but truly no big deal.

The second possibility is a **ground fault**. Current code (and for many years now) requires a **GFCI**, Ground-Fault Circuit Interrupter, for any water-related area, including bathrooms, near sinks in kitchens, hot tubs, etc. You **must** check your electrical situation before using the spa any more. A ground fault can start as a very low-level, not truly dangerous situation and quickly expand to a life-threatening problem.

Start by taking a look at how the wiring is done. Typically the electrical for a spa will go to a separate small panel nearby. That panel in turn will normally have a feed back to the main panel. In one of those locations there should be a GFCI device. In a kitchen or bathroom this will often be a simple 15A or 20A receptacle with GFCI built in. For a spa it will normally be either:

- A breaker in the main panel providing the feed to the spa subpanel.

or

- A breaker in the spa panel that controls all the circuits coming out of the spa panel.

In either case, there should be a TEST button. If you can't find that anywhere, **full stop** - don't use the spa until this is resolved.

If you do find a TEST button, press it. If it turns off the spa (pump, heater, lights, etc.) and you are able to reset it then you have a nominally functional GFCI.

If it does *not* turn off the spa then someone bypassed the GFCI, perhaps due to problems getting everything configured properly or perhaps due to "nuisance trips" that were in fact *danger signals*. If it does not turn off the spa (everything electrical in/on/next to the spa) then **full stop** - you must get this resolved before using the spa again.

There can be additional complications - e.g., if there is low (i.e., ground or near the ground) lighting installed near the spa that was in place *before* the spa was installed then it may be on a circuit *not* routed through the spa panel and not (due to age) required to be GFCI protected when installed. However, when in use around a spa the water danger applies and it should be GFCI protected (whether technically required or not). Wire connections, fixtures, etc. can wear out over time (weather, water, rodents, etc.) and it doesn't take much for a ground fault to show up where the original installation was perfectly safe.

There are more extensive tests that can be done, but the starting point is to determine whether you have proper protection in place, and if you don't then to add it before *anyone* uses the spa again.